# Make texture 100% of width not working as it overflows any other content

Tags: html, css

**Edit:** Here you can see it: https://jsfiddle.net/407r6rc1/ (I cannot recreate the issue for some reason but what I'd like is something like this:)

[image]

Please refer to this screenshot: Notice the ad as it goes over to the footer.

[image]

What I really want is the text area first, then the paragraph of text, and then the ad, then the footer at the end. However, I want the textarea to be 90% of the page width at all times. The user can scroll down to see anything else.

My code structure is this:

```
<body>
<nav>Nav bar stuff here</nav>
<div class="page">
    <div class="page-content">
        <div class="page-main">
            <div class="panel">
                <form>
                    <textarea> Textarea here</textarea>
                </form>
                <p>Text here after the text area</p>
                <div id="ad">Advertisement placed here</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

My css is as following:

```
body, .page, .page-content, .page-main, form {
        height: 100%;
    }

    .panel {
        height: 90%;
    }
```

Visual representation of what I really want:

[image: Visual representation]

Please help me out guys. I've been playing with this issue for the past 2 days, no luck. I feel like I've searched entire stack overflow for this but couldn't find any that fits my issue. Help is highly appreciated.

Regards,

Comment: Please reproduce the issue in a fiddle or so..In a first look, your code seems to be working perfectly. If still there is any issue, may be problem with your CSS. Please post the relevant CSS too..

Comment: I've updated the question sir. https://jsfiddle.net/407r6rc1/ - I'm not able to recreate the issue but I've added a new picture on what I want it to look like. Thank you sir.

Comment: We cannot diagnose your issue if you are unable to replicate it. I would simply say check that your ad div does not have any floats in it as it tends to ignore spacing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 3 items inside your div with class="panel panel-default" and one of those items has been set to take up 100% of the space, leaving no room for the other 2 items. The result is overlap as they are all occupying the same space

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">

    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        size = 100%
    </div>
     <p> Ad and paragraph </p>
</div>
```

Either you need to reduce the size of some of your div classes to correct the space or alternatively split your panel heading and ad paragraph out in to their own div structure. Either method would work fine, but will need to change your height values regardless to account for padding and borders to stop overlap

**Separation method**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                Site name
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h1 class="panel-title">
            Textbox!
        </h1>

    </div>
</nav>

<div class="page">
    <div class="page-content">
        <div class="page-main">

            <div class="panel panel-default">

                <div class="panel-body">

                    <form method="POST">
              <textarea class="form-control editor">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Debitis deleniti dicta dolore eligendi explicabo ipsam non, sapiente vel voluptas voluptate?

              </textarea>
                    </form>

                </div>
            </div>


        </div>
    </div>


</div>
<p><img src="http://www.embertech.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/header-banner.png" alt="Ad and paragraph goes here"/>
    <br>
    <br>
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Debitis deleniti dicta dolore eligendi explicabo ipsam non, sapiente vel voluptas voluptate? Asperiores atque dolore dolorum inventore laudantium nesciunt numquam, optio similique!</span><span>Aut consequuntur fuga libero mollitia qui quia quo veniam. Atque deleniti impedit molestiae numquam recusandae. Aperiam architecto dolor dolorem ea exercitationem, inventore laboriosam, nihil odit quod reprehenderit sunt veniam voluptas.</span>
</p>

<footer class="site-footer">
    <div class="site-footer-legal">© 2016
        <a href="/">SITE NAME</a>
      <span>Footer! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
     </span>
    </div>
</footer>
```

**Compensating for padding**

```
.page-main{
    height: calc(100% - 60px);
    width:100%;
}
```

Comment: Oh my god, _You have 3 items inside your div with class="panel panel-default" and one of those items has been set to take up 100% of the space, leaving no room for the other 2 items._ This is the key. Thanks buddy!